# internal network with bind9 dns; access server by subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, internal-dns

I'm setting up DNS using bind9 on one of my Ubuntu (12.10) boxes under my home network because my router doesn't support DD-WRT or its own DNS.

I set up a zone for "mydomain.net" with an A record for test.mydomain.net and have it pointing to 192.168.1.6 (the statically-assigned ip of the machine in question).

I want to be able to access (via HTTP/browser, mainly) this machine by just using `http://test/`, without having to type in the mydomain.net portion.

I have everything else correctly configured, because I can successfully access `test.mydomain.net` and get the correct Apache response, but I cannot find any particular setting that would allow me to access just `http://test/`.

Here is my named.conf.local file

```
zone "mydomain.net" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.mydomain.net";
};

zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.192";
};
```

and my db.mydomain.net zone file

```
; BIND data file for local
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     mydomain.net. tomprogramming.gmail.com. (
                     2013052603         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
        IN      A       192.168.1.6
;
@       IN      NS      ns.mydomain.net.
@       IN      A       192.168.1.6
@       IN      AAAA    ::1
ns      IN      A       192.168.1.6
test    IN      A       192.168.1.6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refer to a host using short hostnames rather than fully qualified domain names, you simply configure the resolver on your client to search a default domain.  On Unix/Linux clients, you do that by putting

```
search mydomain.net
```

in your `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

Note that `resolv.conf` is frequently automatically managed by DHCP or by your operating system's network configuration (`/etc/network/interfaces` or NetworkManager).  If that is the case, any changes you make to `/etc/resolv.conf` may be overwritten.

Comment: well, this certainly worked.  However, the main purpose for this is to get the machine accessible for my ipad/iphone.  My Windows machines definitely worked due to netbios (though Ive disabled that to test this).  I guess I would have to figure out what @Cha0s said in having the DHCP from my router push the domain down to the machines that I can't manually set a search domain for

Comment: iOS lets you override the Search Domains for your Wi-Fi interface, even when you use DHCP.  That's the quick solution.  The "right" solution might be to get a proper access point that lets you set DHCP options.

Comment: Wow.  So it does.   Somehow I had missed that setting completely.  You're right though, that the "right" answer is to get a proper access point.  That way I don't have to do any particular manual setup for future machines.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually an issue with your DHCP setup.

You need to configure dd-wrt's DHCP Server to push the `mydomain.net` domain to the clients.

That way when you try to access `http://test/` the dns lookup that the client does is for `test.mydomain.net`.

If you have clients with static IPs then you need to configure the search domain to `mydomain.net` in their dns client settings.

Comment: My router serves as my DHCP (though I might end up changing that to my DNS machine as well, if I have to), and doesnt support DD-WRT (its rather old, but does everything that I need it to until now).  Not sure if I can push down the domain

Comment: My mistake, I thought your router was running dd-wrt. Which router do you have? If you setup DHCP on your pc, for ISC DHCP Server the options you are looking for are `option domain-name` and `option domain-search` http://linux.die.net/man/5/dhcp-options

Comment: its a netgear wgr614v9.   There's only a checkbox in the config for "use router as DHCP"

Comment: You can set the domain on the 'Basic ISP Settings' page according to the documentation: http://documentation.netgear.com/wgr614v9/enu/202-10308-01/WGR614v9-03-5.html